# Bitbake not using patch for gcc

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a situation in a distribution based on Yocto 1.7 targetting ARM whereby I'd like to apply a patch to the cross-compiling GCC 4.9.

The regular `bbappend` override mechanism is not working for GCC, which is "special".

I have a `gcc-cross_4.9.bbappend` file which finds its target; but in other respects, it's as if it didn't exist. The patch isn't applied, in spite of removing all the stamp files to force a rebuild from `do_unpack`, `do_patch` and `do_config` onward.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: pay attention to what package is actually being subject to the `do_unpack` and `do_patch`. It is not `gcc-cross` or `gcc`, but `gcc-source`.

The various stages and configurations of `gcc` all share the unpacking steps from the `gcc-source` virtual package; if you target those with patch overrides, nothing happens because none of them execute any unpacking and patching steps.

It is a `gcc-source`-basenamed `.bb` file which controls these steps.

Thus, I simply renamed the `.bbappend` to target the `gcc-source` name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long you took to debug this, but an easy way is by executing

`bitbake-layers show-appends | grep gcc`

You will directly see if your bbappend is taken into account by yocto

Comment: The thing is, the wrong bbappend *is* taken into account by Yocto. Just the manipulations its doing with `SRC_URI` and whatnot are irrelevant. When I run your command, it works whether I have the right name or wrong name, showing exactly what I already know: that my `gcc-whatever_4.9.bbappend` is mated with Poky's `gcc-wbatever_4.9.bb` recipe. Just `whatever` may be `cross` or `source`.